# WD My Book making odd noises (doesn't sound like Click of Death)

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a 2TB WD MyBook connected via Firewire. It is set-up as a 2TB drive (striped) rather than a 1TB drive (mirrored). It is less than 6 months old, contains less than 1TB of data, and is used mainly to store & play video media.

Reads and writes work as expected, however reads have started making an odd clunking noise. At first I thought it might be the Click of Death, but [wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death) has a recording of a WD drive failing and my drive doesn't sound like it.

Should I be worried, or is this common for striped drives? Is there anything I can do to help quiet the sound?

Answer (score 1):

I had a batch of IBM IDE drives that clicked all the time - of course they were fine, but I was always worried.

The click of death may not be the sound you're hearing, but in my opinion, if you can hear a drive and it's less than a year old, it's broken.

If you haven't already, see about making a backup. It's within warranty, so they'll swap it out.

Comment: Thanks. I've no idea how to go about backing-up nearly 1TB of data though. That's a fair-few DVDs!

Comment: Aw, c'mon, them's cheap now! :). I'm mainly worried about your striped data, because that will be tragic if it goes. It may be a fair few DVDs, but perhaps you can borrow an external drive from someone in the meantime.

Comment: @user3463 Three is two, Two is one and One is none. RAID0 doubles your chance of encountering a problem and yet you have no other copy? Time to invest in Crashplan/Carbonite/Backblaze.